# Does Fluoroborate gets used up in Electroplating

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I've been working on Tin electroplating on the side for a while now. I've formulated a mix from my usual electroplating formula template. The mix stubbornly keeps on having the Tin ions form Tin Hydroxide with water. I've tried adding different organics and complexes in hopes of preventing this. But the Hydroxides keep on forming and so the mix does not provide enough Tin ions to allow electroplating at relatively low voltages (at least 16V DC is necessary).

So I finally relented and poured in my "Liquid Tin" http://www.mgchemicals.com/downloads/pdf/specsheets/421.pdf into the mix. Liquid Tin has Stannous Fluoroborate and its the Fluoroborate that keeps the Tin from forming Hydroxides. The effect was really good as plating happens at less than 1V, but then again Liquid Tin is for Electroless plating. After a while it needs higher voltage to electroplate.

So that got me wondering, does the Fluoroborate ion get used up in Electroplating? If there's a danger with Fluorine gas escaping, please also tell me.